# Simple Regular Expression matching

Tags: regex

Im new to regular expressions and Im trying to use RegExp on gwt Client side. I want to do a simple * matching. (say if user enters 006* , I want to match 006...). Im having trouble writing this. What I have is :

```
input = (006*)
input = input.replaceAll("\\*", "(" + "\\" + "\\" + "S\\*" + ")"); 
RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile(input).
```

It returns true with strings like BKLFD006* too. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `^` at the start of the regex you're generating.

The `^` character means to match at the start of the source string only.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing two things here, namely replacement and matching.

Matching is used when you want to extract part of the input string that matches a specific pattern. In your case it seems that is what you want, and in order to get one or more digits that are followed by a star and not preceded by anything then you can use the following regex:

```
^[0-9]+(?=\*)
```

and here is a Java snippet:

```
String subjectString = "006*";
String ResultString = null;
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+(?=\\*)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```

On the other hand, replacement is used when you want to replace a re-occurring pattern from the input string with something else.

For example, if you want to replace all digits followed by a star with the same digits surrounded by parentheses then you can do it like this:

```
String input = "006*";
String result = input.replaceAll("^([0-9]+)\\*", "($1)");
```

Notice the use of `$1` to reference the digits that where captured using the capture group `([0-9]+)` in the regex pattern.